# Add favicon.ico to asp.net core project using webpack

Tags: asp.net, webpack, .net-core

How to add a favicon.ico to a ASP.Net Core project using Webpack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser will look for the favicon.ico by default in the root location so you just have to add the following line to your webpack.config.js file:

```
{ "Locations": [ { "From": "./favicon.ico", "To": "./wwwroot/" }, ] }
```

Once you build and start your project the favicon.ico should have been copied from your original location to the wwwroot.
And you should be able to test it by visiting

`http://localhost:5000/favicon.ico`

No need to add a link to your HTML files.